# relocating the .git folder

Tags: git

I don't think this is possible without a bit of hacking but just throwing it out there.

In Git is it possible to relocate the bulk of the .git folder (/objects i assume) to another location. I am having a problem without my current hard drive filling up with git and i want to be able to move it to a separate hard drive to free up space.

Comment: Wow. Out of curiosity, are you storing binary data in git? I'm just curious because I've never seen a git repo that was over 100mb or so.

Comment: Check out the Linux kernel, dude. Its .git directory is 481 MB. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three possibilities I can think of:

1. The `GIT_DIR` environment variable tells Git where to look for the repository. The default is `.git`, obviously, but you can also set it to `/some/where/else`, if you want.
2. The `GIT_OBJECT_DIR` environment variable does the same, but just for the `.git/objects` subdirectory, not the whole repository.
3. You can use the file `.git/objects/info/alternates` or the environment variable `$GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES` to "borrow" objects from another repository.

See the [git-repositorylayout(5) manual page](http://Kernel.Org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrepository-layout.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Git has a command line option called `--git-dir`. Whenever you run git, use the `--git-dir` option.

```
 git --git-dir=a_different_git_directory status
```

Perhaps you could put that in a batch file or something to make your life easier.

Comment: its worth noting that you need to add a_different_git_directory to your .gitignore file.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the .git directory isn't that big. When is the last time you did a garbage collection?

```
git gc
```

This cleans up unreferenced objects in the git store.