# Git change '.git' folder name in windows

Tags: .net, visual-studio, git

By default git init creates a folder called '.git'. In the recent Visual Studio tools (2005 and up) this works fine. But Visual Studio 2003 (and ... VB6 as well probably) crashes on this foldername. ideally I would like to change this per repository to something like 'git' instead of '.git'. Is this possible?

I know this has been asked before ([relocating the .git folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672655/relocating-the-git-folder)) ... but that was in a linux environment. I'm using windows at work *sigh*.

Hoping there is a simple solution .. otherwise I'll just have to wing it :o But I would rather use sexy git.

edit:

How do you set the GIT_DIR variable on windows? I googled it but it didn't make much sense.

edit2:

Wouldn't an environment variable set it for *all* repositories on that machine? If so I would have to go into every repository and move the folder manually ... also, I tried setting it to 'git' and when I open the git gui app it tells me "cannot use funny .git repository git". When I use the git console it works ... but honestly this is far from a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create all projects at least one level below the repository root.

Comment: Are you saying I should create one gigantic repository? :o

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying ... this might work! :) Going to give it a try.

Answer (score 6):

The GIT_DIR variable allows you to specify another location for the repository.

Comment: How do I do this properly on windows? I tried using git config, etc ... can't figure it out :(

Comment: This article explains how to change environment variables in Windows XP:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, at least, git has a command line option called `--git-dir`. Whenever you run git, use the `--git-dir` option. This should exist in the Windows version too, so you could do

```
 git --git-dir=git_directory status
```

Perhaps you could put that in a batch file or something to make your life easier.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set the GIT_DIR environment variable, using [this Knowledge Base guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suppose the easiest way is to not have any .sln files in the project root.

The project here has about 50 .sln files.

Comment: It also fails when I just open the .vbproj file. (refreshing the tree that is)

Comment: Err, that's not what I meant. Placing the source control project root one level higher than the .sln & .vbproj files is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

as already suggested by Michael

use

```
--git-dir=dirname
```

This works on Windows and Linux

The command must come after the specification of the directory.

```
git --git-dir=.git1234 status
```

this will not work

```
git status --git-dir=.git1234
```

Also git will not ignore .git1234 as it will .git so make sure you add your new dir name to your .gitignore file